# jquery prev()/next() vs native previousElementSibling/nextElementSibling

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsperf.com/next-vs-prev

I'm building a plugin & I have to access the next/previous siblings. As usual I started off with jquery's `prev()` & `next()`. But then, I wanted to increase performance so starting looking for other means of achieving the same.

I got little faster by using `index()` & `eq()` instead.

And finally when I used native javascript's `previousElementSibling` & `nextElementSibling`. The performance gain was significant !

I looked into jquery's source code & am wondering on why jquery is not using these properties internally? is it due to cross browser compatibility issues or something else ?

Comment: For me prev/next is faster that index/eq (Testing in Firefox 17.0 32-bit)

Comment: @Mudassir, which branch of jQuery are you using in your code? Since the two DOM properties you mention are supported in IE9+, I believe the 2.0 branch should be using them internally (I will double-check).

Comment: Okay, I double-checked and 2.1.1-rc2 still does not use `previousElementSibling` and `nextElementSibling`. If performance really is better on all browsers, it would make a good feature request.

Comment: 2.x still has to support IE9, however i too am surprised that jQuery doesn't use this for the browsers that support it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I used this to do the test which is v1.9.1 http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js, let me know if it still makes sense so that I can create an issue(can't see that tab on the github repository though).

Comment: @KevinB Even I thought jquery would be internally looking for the existence of these properties & gracefully degrade for the browsers that don't have this.

Comment: It's important to note that even if jquery did use it, it still wouldn't be as fast as native